# ThreadPolicy Force close in lower android versions

Tags: android

I developed the application in android 4.0 sdk with

```
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

required because of calling external service.

i added

uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5"
in android manifest also.
but getting force close in 2.1,2.2 android versions at the activity where am using ThreadPolicy .

can ant one help to solve this..
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ThreadPolicy` is available since API level 9, so no wonder it doesn't work on earlier versions. You need to find some kind of workaround or just give up using this feature. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any smooth possible way to handle this to work at all versions??

Comment: @Kstar, Sorry, can't answer this question.